# How to keep all rows different in two DataTable?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two DataTable, `dt1`, `dt2`. I write a class to compare two DataTable and get rows different.

table dt1:

```
Col 1       Col 2          Col 3

A            8              @
B            21             ()
```

table dt2:

```
Col 1       Col 2          Col 3

A            8              ^%^%^%
C            827             _++)
```

It show line different like:

`B       21            ()`

I post my function to compare:

```
public static DataTable CompareDataTables(DataTable first, DataTable second)
{
    first.TableName = "FirstTable";
    second.TableName = "SecondTable";

    //Create Empty Table
    DataTable table = new DataTable("Difference");

    try
    {
        //Must use a Dataset to make use of a DataRelation object
        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        {
            //Add tables
            ds.Tables.AddRange(new DataTable[] { first.Copy(), second.Copy() });

            //Get Columns for DataRelation
            DataColumn[] firstcolumns = new DataColumn[ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                firstcolumns[i] = ds.Tables[0].Columns[i];
            }

            DataColumn[] secondcolumns = new DataColumn[ds.Tables[1].Columns.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                secondcolumns[i] = ds.Tables[1].Columns[i];
            }

            //Create DataRelation
            DataRelation r = new DataRelation(string.Empty, firstcolumns, secondcolumns, false);

            ds.Relations.Add(r);

            //Create columns for return table
            for (int i = 0; i < first.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                table.Columns.Add(first.Columns[i].ColumnName, first.Columns[i].DataType);
            }

            //If First Row not in Second, Add to return table.
            table.BeginLoadData();

            foreach (DataRow parentrow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                DataRow[] childrows = parentrow.GetChildRows(r);
                if (childrows == null || childrows.Length == 0)
                    table.LoadDataRow(parentrow.ItemArray, true);
            }

            table.EndLoadData();

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
    return table;
}
```

`tableDifferent` will contain all rows different.

```
DataTable tableDifferent;
tableDifferent = CompareDataTables(dt1, dt2);
```

I tried with code:

```
var rowsToDelete = from r1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                   join r2 in tableDifferent.AsEnumerable()
                        on r1.Field<String>("StudentID") equals r2.Field<String>("StudentID")
                   select r1;
```

Now, I want to remove all rows in `dt1` and `dt2`, only keep all rows in `tableDifferent`.

Have any method to do this?

Comment: have you tried ' and ' keyword instead of your 2nd on?

Comment: Hey bro, if I get `rowsToDetele`, how to remove all rows expect `rowsToDelete`?

Comment: @VănLộc If `tableDifferent` contains all unique rows, just use it.

Comment: @VănLộc What do you mean by rows different ? You mean in d1 not in d2 and in d2 not in d1. Can you give an example of input and output ? It is not clear.

Comment: @user3185569 I updated my question. With example and full class to compare two DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

If the only problem left is to clear the other data tables, you can use the [DataTable.Clear Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> All rows in all tables are removed. An exception is generated if the
>   table has any enforced child relations that would cause child rows to
>   be orphaned.
>
> If the DataSet is bound to an XmlDataDocument, calling DataSet.Clear
>   or DataTable.Clear raises the NotSupportedException. To avoid this
>   situation, traverse each table, removing each row one at a time. When
>   you use NewRow to create new rows, the rows must be processed before
>   you call Clear

In your case:

```
dt1.Clear();
dt2.Clear();
```